# MAC address to IPv6 link-local address online conversion in perl

Tags: perl, ipv6

I have the MAC address of the machine. how to convert it to IPv6 link-local address(EUI-64 format) in perl?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the modified EUI-64, refer to [RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#appendix-A) for the algorithm.

Basically, you take the 48-bit MAC address, split it in half, insert `FFFE` to extend it to 64 bits, and flip the U/L bit.